# Unique recordcount

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table with the following model for an internal Analytics

```
int UserID
DateTime TimeStamp
int NodeID
```

Let's say we have the following data.

```
Record 1 { UserID = 5, DateTime = 28-02-2022 11:00, NodeID = 1 }
Record 2 { UserID = 4, DateTime = 28-02-2022 11:01  NodeID = 1 }
Record 3 { UserID = 4, DateTime = 28-02-2022 11:04  NodeID = 1 }
Record 4 { UserID = 4, DateTime = 28-02-2022 11:07  NodeID = 2 }
```

To get the total visit pr. node i got

```
Select NodeID, Count(NodeID)
from Table
Group By NodeID
```

Which gives

```
Node 1 Count = 3
Node 2 Count = 1
```

My question is: How do I in SQL get the unique Node count?

```
Node 1 Count = 2
Node 2 Count = 1
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you use count and group by

- to get the number of lines per node

```sql
select nodeId node , count(*) row_per_node
from SQLtable
group by nodeID
```

- to get the number of users per node

```
select nodeId node , count(distinct userid) count_user_node
from SQLtable
group by nodeID
```

Comment: Note that this will raise a syntax error on most dbms's. (ANSI SQL has double quotes for delimited identifiers, e.g. `"count"`.)

Comment: Thank you @jarlh. I've changed the alias to avoid the need of quotes. I'll keep the double quotes in mind for another time. I've tested in DBfiddle and it does seem to be the universal solution compared to 'name' and [name] which cause errors with certain dbms. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this is close, you can use programming to do the logic

```
Select NodeID, Count(NodeID) from Table Group By NodeID, UserID
```